# QGIS Spatial Index uses bounding boxes; how to get actual nearest line to a known point

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, distance, proximity

I have looked at lots of answers referring to this same issue, and tried using QGIS Spatial Indexes and iterating through the line features in the spatial index to calculate the distance between a point and a line, but `pt.distance` requires either `pt.distance(float, float)` or `pt.distance(QgsPoint)`. `pt.distance` won't accept `nnfeature.geometry()` if that geometry is a line. Is there a way to refer to line as points that are 1m apart?

```
# Find a nearest index entry to myPoint (QgsPoint)
nearestindexid = spacialIndex.nearestNeighbor(pt, 1)[0]
# Get the feature in the layer (self.myvectorlayer) that is
# being indexed by self.spIndex
nnfeature = featureID_Layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(nearestindexid)).next()
# Get the distance to this feature (it is not necessarily the nearest one)
mindistance = pt.distance(nnfeature.geometry())
```

The above line is where I get an error. Python or QGIS can't find the distance between a point a line geometry. If `nnfeature` was a point geometry, it would work.

```
px = pt.x()
py = pt.y()
# Get all the features that may be closer to the point than nnfeature
closefeatureids = spacialIndex.intersects(QgsRectangle(px - mindistance,
                   py - mindistance, px + mindistance, py + mindistance))
for closefeatureid in closefeatureids:
    closefeature = featureID_Layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(closefeatureid)).next()
    thisdistance = pt.distance(closefeature.geometry())

    # Python or QGIS doesn't like the line above either

    if thisdistance < mindistance:
        mindistance = thisdistance
        nnfeature = closefeature
        if mindistance == 0:
             break
#End of New NN logic

genericFeat2 = QgsFeature()
#convert from new NN logic
genericFeat2=nnfeature
idx = featureID_Layer.fieldNameIndex(fieldname)
closestFeatureFieldNameString=str(genericFeat2.attributes()[idx])
return closestFeatureFieldNameString
```

Answer (score 5):

If `pt` is type of `QgsPoint`, you should convert it to`QgsGeometry` and then use `.distance()` function.

```
pt_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt)    
mindistance = pt_geom.distance(nnfeature.geometry())
```

`QgsPoint`, `QgsPolyline`, `QgsPolygon` etc. are not a geometry in PyQGIS, they're all `QVector`s. They have to be converted to `QgsGeometry` before they are used for spatial analyses.